# emails: server sends but a user doesn't receive

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, actionmailer

I'm facing a weird bug.

Trying to set up welcome email after a user's registration.

According to server logs, my code sends an email but a user doesn't receive it.

Here is my code:

`models/user.rb`

```
after_create :welcome_message

  private
    def welcome_message
      UserMailer.welcome_email(self).deliver
    end
```

and `mailers/user_mailer.rb`

```
def welcome_email(user)
    @user = user
    mail to: @user.email, subject: t("mailer.welcome_email.welcome")
  end
```

here are environments. The error occurs in both of them

`config/environments/development.rb`

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost:3000' }
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  address:              'smtp.mandrillapp.com',
  port:                 '587',
  domain:               'localhost:3000',
  user_name:            'welcome@mysite.com',
  password:             'blahblahblah',
  authentication:       'plain',
  enable_starttls_auto: true
}
```

and `config/environments/production.rb`

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'mysite.com' }
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  address:              'smtp.mandrillapp.com',
  port:                 '587',
  domain:               'mysite.com',
  user_name:            'welcome@mysite.com',
  password:             'blahblahblah',
  authentication:       'plain',
  enable_starttls_auto: true
}
```

I'm using Devise to register users. So, also tried to do that via :confirmable. Outcome is the same – test user doesn't get a welcome email.

`Gemfile`

```
gem 'rails', '3.2.12'
gem 'devise', '3.0.3'
gem "mail"
```

and here are server logs

```
Sent mail to user@hismail.com (1920ms)
Date: Sat, 10 May 2014
From: welcome@mysite.com
Reply-To: welcome@mysite.com
To: user@hismail.com
Message-ID: <aaa@aaa.mail>
Subject: Confirmation instructions
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html;
charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

<p>Welcome user@hismail.com!</p>
```

Yet eventually there is no welcome email at user@hismail.com

Any ideas?

UPD:
on the internet I see that nobody else faces the same problem
So, I guess I'm just missing something. But cannot figure out what and where. Please help me.

Comment: Mandrill provides API logs for all activity. It's available from the menu in the top-right. Does this show that your app is reaching mandrill and asking it to send the mail?

Comment: No... I see `You don't have any failed API calls`and `You don't have any successful API calls yet`. Interesting. I'm new to Mandrill. That means that in fact no emails were sent. Where is my fault?

Comment: What do you have `config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors` set to? If it's not set (I think it's default might be `false`), try setting: `config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true` and checking your logs at that stage.

Just checking, you should also have your Mandrill API keys set as the user_name and password for the SMTP settings, rather than your Mandrill account details.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

Create a file named as setup_mail.rb in config/initializers/ folder so that it looks like

```
config/initializers/setup_mail.rb
```

and put the below code in that file:-

```
ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method = :smtp
ActionMailer::Base.perform_deliveries = true
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
 :address => "smtp.mandrillapp.com",
 :domain => "mysite.com",
 :port => 80,
 :user_name => "username",
 :password => "blahblahblah",
 :authentication => :plain
}

ActionMailer::Base.default_url_options[:host] = "mysite.com"
```

Delete this from **config/environments/development.rb** and **config/environments/production.rb**

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost:3000' }
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
 address:              'smtp.mandrillapp.com',
 port:                 '587',
 domain:               'localhost:3000',
 user_name:            'welcome@mysite.com',
 password:             'blahblahblah',
 authentication:       'plain',
 enable_starttls_auto: true
}
```

Comment: Huh, thanks for the piece of advice but still doesn't work. And besides creating a user became very slooooww... Tried to test that on "Forgot password"and see the same – a very slow working page and no emails in my inbox (holy hell!)

Comment: Also, `:user_name => "username"`and `user_name: 'welcome@mysite.com'` aren't the same?

Comment: :user_name => "username", replace username with your username

Comment: did that but still no result ((