# SMTP settings not sending emails to hotmail,msn, microsoft accounts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, smtp

I have added the smtp settings in production. But it does not send any mail to hotmail, msn, microsoft accounts.

```
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
      :address => "host.abc.com",       
      :port => 25,
      :domain => "abcd.com",
      :user_name => 'abc@mymail.com',
      :password => 'XXXXXX',
      :authentication => 'plain'
}
```

Is there anything I missed, any help would appreciate .

Thanks

Comment: try with the configuration of smtp  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23581807/emails-server-sends-but-a-user-doesnt-receive/23589815#23589815

Answer (score 0):

Have you included the `config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost:3000' }` into your **environments/development.rb**?

Comment: This is a case of production env, also all the other settings are ok.

Comment: Reworded:  Are domains other than Microsoft receiving email from your site?

Comment: Yes 100% successfully

Comment: Use [MxToolbox](http://mxtoolbox.com) to see if your domain has been blacklisted by any Spammer watch lists.

Comment: Also look into adding a SPF DNS record to your sending domain.